# JavaScriptOwnership context object is garbage collected

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

The following program demonstrates the issue I'm having:

```
class App : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    virtual ~App() = default;
    Q_INVOKABLE bool f() const {
        return false;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlEngine engine;

    QObject* ctx = new App();
    QQmlEngine::setObjectOwnership(ctx, QQmlEngine::JavaScriptOwnership);
    engine.rootContext()->setContextObject(ctx);

    QQmlComponent component(&engine);
    QObject::connect(&component, &QQmlComponent::statusChanged, [&](auto status) {
        if(status == QQmlComponent::Ready) component.create(); 
        if(status == QQmlComponent::Error) {
          for(auto err : component.errors()) qCritical() << "Error: " << err.toString();
        }
    });
    component.loadUrl(QUrl::fromLocalFile("main.qml"));

    return app.exec();
}
```

With the QML document:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {

    Timer {
        interval: 1; running: true; repeat: true
        onTriggered: {
            console.log("call f");
            f(); gc();
            console.log("done");
        }
    }

}
```

If I run this, it outputs:

```
$ ./main
qml: call f
qml: done
qml: call f
file:///data/libs/hsqml/member-undefined/main.qml:10: ReferenceError: f is not defined
qml: call f
fish: './main' terminated by signal SIGSEGV (Adressbereichsfehler)
```

Is this expected behavior? When is it possible to use QQmlEngine::JavaScriptOwnership safely?

Comment: I got it working with `QQmlApplicationEngine`, `QQmlContext::setContextProperty`, and `QQuickWindow::show()`. Does it look like an acceptable workaround for your problem?

Comment: @Armaghast unfortunately, this example is extracted from an API that a library needs to provide, so I cannot just switch the library to QQmlContext::setProperty. Also, I would like to know, why does it work that way? Is it just because the window now holds a reference to it?

Comment: Sadly, I don't know sufficiently QML internals/JS gc; with `QQmlContext::setProperty("ctx", ctx)`, `f()` is replaced by `ctx.f()`, which seems to impact garbage collection. I suggest you post it on http://forum.qt.io/category/12/qt-quick (and answer your own SO question once you have a solution)

Comment: What is part of the library / what is part of your code? Removing `QQmlEngine::setObjectOwnership(...)` and setting `QQmlComponent component` as `ctx`'s parent works.

Comment: The whole thing is part of a library, which I'm currently trying to fix. As the library is also using `JavaScriptOwnership` in a few other places (where it's really required), I'd also like to know when it's safe to do so so I really want to understand what's going on.

Comment: ctx object is destroyed when you run the garbage collector, cause your app assume that this object is no longer used    https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management   . To prevent gc from deleting your obj move ownership to cpp `QQmlEngine::setObjectOwnership(ctx, QQmlEngine::CppOwnership);`